# How do I return a specific value from a plist file?

Tags: arrays, swift, plist

So I have a plist file called Computer and its got 5 items on it.

Each item has these keys:

```
Type
Price
UniqueCode
```

For example

> Item 0
>
> Type: Desktop, Price 100, UniqueCode 321
>
> Item 1
>
> Type: Tablet, Price 150, UniqueCode 322
>
> Item 2
>
> Type: Laptop, Price 200, UniqueCode 323
>
> Item 3
>
> Type: Desktop, Price 210, UniqueCode 324
>
> Item 4
>
> Type: Laptop, Price 400, UniqueCode 325

Then I have a class:

And I have put the following code:

```
var emojiArray: NSArray?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Computer", ofType: "plist"){
    emojiArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```

I am aware that it is incomplete but that's how far I could only get. My main objective is to display the price of Computers with the UniqueCode 321 and 324 and at the same time I must also half their prices.

How would I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are strongly discouraged from using `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift because Foundation collection types lack type information. The recommended class to deserialize property lists is `PropertyListSerialization`.

The (Swift 3) code prints the values for `UniqueCode` and half of `Price` for all items whose `UniqueCode` is in `uniqueCodes`

```
let uniqueCodes = [321, 324]

if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Computer", withExtension: "plist") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
        let emojiArray = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
        let filteredArray = emojiArray.filter{ uniqueCodes.contains($0["UniqueCode"] as! Int)}
        for item in filteredArray {
            print(item["UniqueCode"] as! Int, item["Price"] as! Int / 2)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The Swift 2 equivalents (as far as I remember) are

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().urlForResource("Computer", withExtension: "plist") {
...
let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL:url)
let emojiArray = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListFromData(data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

If the Swift 2 syntax is wrong please comment out the lines and retype them using code completion.

Comment: Hi there, I'm using Swift 2 and I'm getting an error it says "Use of unresolves identifier 'Bundle' thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are using something *older* than Xcode 8 (i.e. you are using Swift 2.3 or older).

Comment: @vadian Im getting an error at this line "let data = try Data(contentsOfURL:url)" its saying "Expected expression after operator

Comment: Sorry, it's `NSData`

Comment: @vadian Thanks that fixed it but another error appears. It now says "Use of unresolved identifier 'url'.. Sorry for too many fix requests.

Comment: `url` what? Which line?

Comment: @vadian this line "let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL:url)" The "url" part has got a red highlight.

Comment: That's impossible. `url` is defined in the `if let` line above

Comment: Oh.. Sorry for wasting your time. I did not copy that part of the code. Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 1):

From your plist description, it sounds like you have an array of dictionaries.

Something that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>Desktop</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
        <key>Unique Code</key>
        <integer>321</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>Laptop</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <integer>400</integer>
        <key>Unique Code</key>
        <integer>235</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

So once you get your emojiArray loaded, you can iterate through the array and get the values you're looking for.

E.G. something like:

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Computer", ofType: "plist") {
        if let emojiArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {

            if let typedEmojiArray = emojiArray as? Array< Dictionary< String, AnyObject > > {
            for eachEntry in typedEmojiArray {
                    if let uniqueCode = eachEntry["Unique Code"] as? NSNumber {
                        if let computerType = eachEntry["Type"] as? String {
                            print("computer type is \(computerType) and unique code is \(uniqueCode)")
                        }

                        if uniqueCode == 321 {
                            print("this is a value we wanted")
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is done in Swift 3, b.t.w.

Additionally, Plists like this aren't necessarily the best way to store data in a file.  If this were my app, I'd probably try to use CoreData (to persist the data between launches).

Comment: Oh, I can't agree with that. Core Data is not a beginner technology. And it is certainly not appropriate if all you want to do is persist some data. I see it used _way_ too much, unnecessarily, as it is.